# Selenium : Sending enter command to text box gives unknown error: unexpected command response

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi guys i am new on selenium i tried to search from website's textbox

There is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
s=Service(PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url='https://www.techwithtim.net/'
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
search=driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="s")
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(5)
driver.close() #driver
```

The program is able to search, but it throws an error at the search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) line and exits the code.

I can't give all error for you because of this website doesn't allow i don't know

so some of the error:

```
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/us1/selen.py", line 16, in <module>
    search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\us1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 223, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\us1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 396, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\us1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\us1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: unexpected command response
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.66)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00F36463+2188387]
    Ordinal0 [0x00ECE461+1762401]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DE3D78+802168]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DD7210+750096]
.
.
.
```

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar it has still the same error i am sorry thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I faced the same error on my desktop, turns out that this has something to do with version mismatch.

My chrome version was

```
Version 103.0.5060.66 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

So I updated my chrome driver to version

```
103.0.5060.53
```

You can try updating your chrome and chrome driver accordingly.

- If you are using Chrome version `104`, please download ChromeDriver `104.0.5112.20`
- If you are using Chrome version `103`, please download ChromeDriver `103.0.5060.53`
- If you are using Chrome version `102`, please download ChromeDriver `102.0.5005.61`

[Chrome Driver download link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

You can check your chrome version here `chrome://settings/help`

Once updated, the below code should work fine

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
s = Service(chrome_path)
url = 'https://www.techwithtim.net/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()
search=driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="search-field")
```

Comment: <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search..." value name = "s" >               in here is value name not "s"? i will try your solution now

Comment: no i have still same error

Comment: what?? please check, it works correctly on my setup

Comment: I checked i have the same error, the error wasnt in search=driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="search-field") part, it occurs when search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: @simonkerike can you try again with my updated answer

Comment: how can i update my chrome? yes you are right mine is 103.0.5060.66 too

Comment: You can keep the chrome version as is, just download the driver from the link O mentioned above. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246098/discussion-between-simonkerike-and-himanshu-poddar).

Answer (score 0):

You have to download chrome driver exe from below path as per installed chrome version and use the respective chrome driver. Selenium works on chromedriver.exe. You have to download the chrome driver exe and paste it in your computer and in path you have to give location of the chrome driver exe.

```
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.techwithtim.net/")
```

Answer (score 0):

When I got the `unexpected command response` today, the solution was just to **wait for 1 second** before sending any Selenium commands to the Chrome browser. It seems the browser needed a moment to warm up before being ready to receive commands.